# Unity 2017 with Firebase 4.2. App Works in Unity Editor, but fail when run the app on Android. Firebase connection error

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm working on Unity 2017.2.0f3 and Firebase SDK 4.2.1 it work when I run it on PC in Unity Editor environment, when I build it to apk and run it on Android devices, Firebase give me an error.

My code:

```
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12FileName("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-admin-sdk.p12"); 
 FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorServiceAccountEmail("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"); 
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12Password("notasecret");
    FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
    dependencyStatus = task.Result;
    if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available) {
    InitializeFirebase();
    } else {
    Debug.LogError(
    "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
    }
    });
```

I'm using service account to connect, It works perfect on Unity Editor when I run the app. But when I generate the APK and install it on the android device (Samsung S7, Android 7.0), when I run the app the LogCat give me this error:

```
11-22 21:23:58.819: E/Unity(5835): Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.ValueEventRegistration:FireCancelEvent(DatabaseError)
11-22 21:23:58.819: E/Unity(5835): Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.View.CancelEvent:Fire()
11-22 21:23:58.819: E/Unity(5835): Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.View.Runnable30:Run()
```

Error also is reported on this link: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/120

Any help is welcome....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I made couple mistakes, finally I fixed. For some reason it is not enough have setting up the service account on you project to read/write data from Firebase Real-time Database. It works on Unity Editor when you run the game. But when you isntall the APK on mobile device (Android), App(Game) has to authenticate a valid Firebase user

I created a user signing method EMAIL/PASSWORD on Firebase console. then I did the authentication on may app using Firabase Authetication Unity Package, and Voila...it works.
When user is been authenticate on Firebase, the Firebase system automatically change the Real-time database rules to TRUE

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start

My working code, even on Unity Editor and on mobile device:

```
private Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
private Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser;

void Awake() {
    //Using Firebase SDK
    //This is needed only for the unity editor
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12FileName("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-admin-sdk.p12");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorServiceAccountEmail("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.gserviceaccount.com");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12Password("notasecret");
    //--------------------------------------

    FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available) {
            InitializeFirebase();
        } else {
            Debug.LogError(
              "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
        }
    });
}

// Initialize the Firebase database:
protected virtual void InitializeFirebase() {
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
    // NOTE: You'll need to replace this url with your Firebase App's database
    // path in order for the database connection to work correctly in editor

    //This is needed only for the unity editor
    app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://xxxx.yyyyyyyyy.com/");
    if (app.Options.DatabaseUrl != null) app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(app.Options.DatabaseUrl);
    //--------------------------------------
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("mail@mail.com", "strongpassword").ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCanceled) {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
            newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        //Getting client id for FB using device id
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("node1").Child(node2).Child("node3")
        .ValueChanged += HandleChanged;
    });
}
```

Note: password should be strong.
Don't forget to do a sign out on destroy method, otherwise you will get and error next time you try to connect.

```
auth.SignOut();
```